# Replace whole paragraph on multiple pages

Tags: wp-admin

I have many almost identical pages on my web page for seo purposes, I would like to change rewrite an entire block of text to something else, is this possible to do in one go as it would take ages to do individually?

many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query should work for you. As seen [here](https://speckyboy.com/wordpress-sql-query-snippets/):

> **Search and Replace WordPress Post Content**
>
> To search and replace post content, use the following code. Replace
>   OriginalText with the current text and replace NewText with your new
>   text.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET 'post_content' = REPLACE ('post_content',
'OriginalText',
'NewText'
);
```

I would try this [“SearchReplace”](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin myself.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to:

- Change a block of text with a different content on each post >> A search/replace in database is the best option
- Or replace on each post a text block by another similar content? >> Plugins [like this one would be better](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sheet-editor-bulk-spreadsheet-editor-for-posts-and-pages/)